# Assignment problems: Credit card validation

Tags: java, validation

Quoted from my assignment: The objectives of this question are
(a) to practice selection structure
(b) to apply iteration structure
(c) to manipulate string

```
do {
    System.out.print("Enter MC for MasterCard or VISA for VISA card: ");
    cardType = scn.next();
} while (!cardType.equals("MC") && !cardType.equals("VISA"));
if (cardType.equals("MC")) {
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter MasterCard card no.: "); // Get input:
                                                            // mastercard
                                                            // number
        cardNo = scn.nextLong();
        cardLength = Long.toString(cardNo).length(); // Get length of
                                                        // mastercard
                                                        // number input
        dbUserPrefix = cardNo / java.lang.Math.pow(10, 14);
        intUserPrefix = (int) dbUserPrefix;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {// for validating prefix
            // 4 possibilities
            if (intUserPrefix == cardPrefix[i]) {
                if (cardLength == 16) { // Prefix & length correct                      break;
                } else { // Prefix correct, length wrong
                    state = 1;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (cardLength == 16) { // Prefix wrong, length correct                     state = 2;
                } else { // Prefix & length incorrect
                    state = 3;
                }
            }
        }
        if (state == 0) {
            System.out.println("SUCESS");
        } else if (state == 1) {
            System.out.println("Your length of card number is incorrect.");
        } else if (state == 2) {
            System.out.println("Your card prefix is incorrect.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your card prefix and length of card number is incorrect.");
        }
        break;
    } while (cardLength != 16);
}
```

The main thing I want here is the program to validate that the right Prefix of a credit card is 51,52,53,54 or 55. and the right length to be 16 (number of digits). If validation fails, the error must be printed out. Problem is that other than prefix==51, the rest of the prefix i tried results in state==2.

Comment: Why not use a switch statement here?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Why was `variable-assignment` retagged in this question? It has nothing specifically to do with variable assignment, and it was most likely an oversight by the asker with the synonyms of *assignment*.

Answer (score 2):

I would go about this in a different way. You take your input (the card number) as a long. I think it'd be easier to do this sort of validation if you took it as a string.

To validate length, where `cardNum` is of type String:

```
boolean isValidLength = (cardNum.length() == 16);
```

To get prefix:

```
String prefix = cardNum.substring(0,2); // gets first two digits of cardNum
```

To validate, I'd put all of the valid prefixes in a list and call `.contains()`:

```
List<String> validPrefixes = new ArrayList<String>();
validPrefixes.add("52");
// ... etc

boolean isValidPrefix = validPrefixes.contains(prefix);
```

Then your logic would go something like this:

1. Prompt user for number
2. Take input as a String
3. Check the input length is correct; if not return error
4. Check that the prefix is correct; if not return error
5. Return success